# How can I change css styles with javaScript by date condition?

Tags: javascript

I was wonder if anyone can tell me why this isn’t working? I am trying to switch display of div.

```
function testDatum(){
    var vandaag = new Date();
    var eindDatum = new Date('04/15/2018');
    if (vandaag > eindDatum){
        document.getElementById('Div1').style.display = 'none';
    } 
    else {
        document.getElementById('Div2').style.display = 'none';
    }   
}
```

Comment: Call the function and DRY `document.getElementById(vandaag > eindDatum ? "Div1" : "Div2").style.display = 'none';`

Answer (score 0):

The code works....

```js
function testDatum(){
    var vandaag = new Date();
    var eindDatum = new Date('05/15/2018');
    if (vandaag > eindDatum){
        document.getElementById('Div1').style.display = 'none';
    } 
    else {
        document.getElementById('Div2').style.display = 'none';
    }   
}

testDatum()
```

```html
<div id="Div1">Div1</div>
<div id="Div2">Div2</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps OP was forgetting to call the function.

Answer (score 0):

What you have written, It's absolute current but you didn't declare the function. So, You didn't get any result.

declare function now you get result.
testDatum();